# How to dynamically add columns to an existing database in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i use ruby on rails on my backend and mysql2 as database, and as you can guess from my nickname i'm newbie in rails.

```
{
  "last_viewed_categorie" : "shirt",
  "last_name" : "herose",
  "login_screen_apperaed" : 1,
  "item_added_to_cart"  : 5,
  "first_name" : "george"
}
```

this is the json format that i'm currently receiving to my database. What i want is this something like that

```
jsonColumns //array that contains keys of json

jsonColumns.each do |jsonColumn|
unless @existingColumnNames.include?(jsonColumn)

"Alter table mutable add_column #{jsonColumn}"
```

I can't seem to find any way to make something like this to run,

Is it even possible?

if it's not possible can you offer a similar one?

Thank you

Comment: `mysql2` would be your database driver, and MySQL is your database. Also worth noting, variable names in Ruby are, by tradition, expressed like `json_columns`.

Comment: TL:DR DON'T. What will stop people from creating their own JSON requests with random column names? You will have a completely messed up DB that Rails cannot use.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamically altering the table is not something you want to do. A better plan is to use a serialized column, something where you create a `LONGBLOB` column that can store arbitrary data, and declare that with `serialize` in your model.

The ActiveRecord layer in Rails actually requires your schema to be static, unchanging, apart from scheduled migrations. Introducing arbitrary columns at run-time makes the column cache inconsistent and can lead to problems.

If you're handling a lot of JSON data, you may want to consider using [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) which has a [native JSON column type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) that is supported by Rails. This makes storing, querying, and manipulating those results a lot easier.

Comment: i tested between sqlite postgresql and mysql the best performance came from mysql, i can't seem to understand your solution offer.So i create columns from start and than give them names?That makes sense but can you show me a little bit on how can i do that?

Comment: What did "best performance" mean? I'm not sure how you tested these or if/how they were tuned. Generally models are created with a [migration script](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) when you run `rails generate model model_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code inside your loop.

```
 add_column :mutable, :jsonColumn, :text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a gem for that. Check this out

https://github.com/Liooo/dynabute

Also, this question is a duplication of

[Rails: dynamic columns/attributes on models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029700/rails-dynamic-columns-attributes-on-models)